# Apache2 failed to start downgrading PHP to 7.4 on Ubuntu 22

Tags: apache2

After downgrading php version from 8.1 to 7.4

If I restart the apache2 it fails

```bash
sudo a2dismod php8.1
sudo a2enmod php7.4
systemctl restart apache2
```

I get below error
 `apache2: Syntax error on line 146 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 3 of /etc/apache2/mod>`

In `apache2.conf` below code is found

```
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
```

Comment: Have you checked the `apache2.conf` file to correct the syntax error? 

Comment: please send contents of `/etc/apache2/mod.....`, apache2.conf:146 probably just imports the modules

Comment: I have this code `IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load` @matigo

Answer (score 0):

The syntax has been changed in Ubuntu 22.04. In `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php7.4.load` (or a similar file), change:

`LoadModule php7_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.4.so`

to

`LoadModule php_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.4.so`

After this change, just restart apache2 with `sudo systemctl restart apache2`.